# Как получить коллекцию, которая находится через несколько связей

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Приветствую!

Народ, подскажите, как поступить.

Имеем несколько таблиц:

*countries*:

```
id
name
```

*users*:

```
id
name
email
```

(pivot table) *country_users*:

```
country_id
user_id
```

*posts*:

```
id
users_id
body
```

Как мне получить посты, зная страну? =)

Страны с пользователями связаны многие-ко-многим, а вот пользователи с постами - один-ко-многим.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться отношением hasManyThrough.
http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/eloquent#has-many-through

Comment: Не получится, ибо я использую pivot-таблицу :(